# Qt QWidget disable re sizing more than minimum size needed

Tags: c++, qt, layout

I have a `QGridLayout` inside a `QWidget`. I keep adding child `QGridLayouts` to this. I want the `QWidget` to resize according to the size needed for child layouts but for the user to be unable to resize it.

MainWindow.cpp (`MainWindow` is inherited from `QWidget`)

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    QGridLayout *mainLayout = new QGridLayout();
    {
        AAController *ac1 = new AAController("Ins1");
        AAController *ac2 = new AAController("Ins2");
        AAController *ac3 = new AAController("Ins3");

        mainLayout->addLayout(ac1, 0, 0);
        mainLayout->addLayout(ac2, 0, 1);
        mainLayout->addLayout(ac3, 1, 1);
    }
    setLayout(mainLayout);
}
```

AAController.cpp (`AAController` is inherited from `QGridLayout`)

```
AAController::AAController(const QString& instrument)
    :_instrument(instrument)
{
    _lblInstrument = new QLabel(_instrument);
    _lblMismatchThreshold = new QLabel("Mismatch threshold : ");
    _lblQuoteVolume = new QLabel("Quote volume : ");
    _btnUpdateAlgo = new QPushButton("Update Algo");
    _spnMismatchThreshold = new QSpinBox();
    _spnQuoteVolume = new QSpinBox();

    this->addWidget(_lblInstrument, 0, 1, 1, 2, Qt::AlignCenter);
    this->addWidget(_lblMismatchThreshold, 1, 0, 1, 2);
    this->addWidget(_lblQuoteVolume, 2, 0, 1, 2);
    this->addWidget(_btnUpdateAlgo, 3, 2, 1, 2);
    this->addWidget(_spnMismatchThreshold, 1, 3);
    this->addWidget(_spnQuoteVolume, 2, 3);

    setSizeConstraint(SetFixedSize);
}
```

I get something like this:

[image]

But at the moment I can resize this like:

[image]

I want to disable such resizing. How do I do this?

Comment: Just set your MainWindow to Fixed Size. When adding Children set it to Minimum and set it back to fixed size after.

Comment: Probably not duplicate, since its no StatusBar nor a QDialog.

Comment: @SebastianLange: Your method results in a fixed size window. But larger than the minimum as in the first image above.

Comment: `setFixedSize(0,0)` in `MainWindow` works. It shows the resize cursor at the window's border but actually can't resize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in your main window:

```
this->layout()->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetFixedSize);
```

This is the result i got:

[image]

Comment: Please have a look at the comment to SebastianLange above

Comment: @nakiya See my edit. Is this the result you're looking for?